# dataframe to spatial and intersection with a circular buffer

Tags: python, gis

I have a dataframe that contains lon/lat information. The aim is to find all the points within a `rad` distance  to a specific point `st_p`.
In fact I kind of have already have the code in R, but I need to do the same on python.

Here what I do is that,  I convert the dataframes to `sf` objects, I define a buffer, the I make the intersection with the buffer.

Here is the R code.
I just dont know what libraries to use in Python in order to do the same.

```r
within_radius <- function(df, st_p, rad) {
  
  # Transform to an sf object and cahnge from lon/lat to utm
  sf_df <- st_transform(st_as_sf(
    df,
    coords = c("lon", "lat"),
    crs = 4326,
    agr = "constant"
  ), 6622)
  
  # Create an utm st point based on the coordinates of the stop point 
  cntr <- st_transform(st_sfc(st_p, crs = 4326), 6622)
  
  # Craete a circular buffer with the given radius
  buff <- st_buffer(cntr, rad)
  
  # Filter the points that are within the buffer
  intr <- st_intersects(sf_df, buff, sparse = F)
  sf_df <- st_transform(sf_df, 4326)
  sf_df <- sf_df[which(unlist(intr)), ]
  
  # Compute the distance of esch point to the begining of the road segment
  xy = st_coordinates(st_centroid(sf_df))
  nc.sort = sf_df[order(xy[, "X"], xy[, "Y"]), ]
  sf_df <- nc.sort %>%
    mutate(dist = st_distance(
      x = nc.sort,
      y = nc.sort[1, ],
      by_element = TRUE
    ))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `geopandas` and `shapely` to do pretty much anything

- Create a geopandas geodataframe from a pandas dataframe with lat, lng:

```
    In [19]: import pandas as pd
    
    In [20]: import geopandas as gpd
    
    In [21]: from shapely.geometry import Point
    
    In [22]: df = pd.DataFrame({"lat": [19.435175, 19.432909], "lng":[-99.141197, -99.146036]})
    
    In [23]: gf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry = [Point(x,y) for (x,y) in zip(df.lng, df.lat)], crs = "epsg:4326")
    
    In [24]: gf
    Out[24]:
             lat        lng                    geometry
    0  19.435175 -99.141197  POINT (-99.14120 19.43518)
    1  19.432909 -99.

    146036  POINT (-99.14604 19.43291)
```

buffer, projections and other operations are available for a geodataframe, this is how you convert to a metric projection and create a 10m buffer:

```
    In [27]: gf.to_crs(6622).buffer(10)
    Out[27]:
    0    POLYGON ((-3597495.980 -2115793.588, -3597496....
    1    POLYGON ((-3598149.053 -2115813.383, -3598149....
    dtype: geometry
```

You can call intersects to get the intersection between a buffer and a point:

```
    In [29]: gf.to_crs(6622).buffer(10).intersects(Point(-3597505.980,-2115793.588))
    Out[29]:
    0     True
    1    False
    dtype: bool
```

compute centroids:

```
    In [30]: gf.to_crs(6622).buffer(10).centroid
    Out[30]:
    0    POINT (-3597505.980 -2115793.588)
    1    POINT (-3598159.053 -2115813.383)
    dtype: geometry
```

filter using the buffer:

```
    In [31]: gf.loc[gf.to_crs(6622).buffer(10).intersects(Point(-3597505.980,-2115793.588))]
    Out[31]:
             lat        lng                    geometry
    0  19.435175 -99.141197  POINT (-99.14120 19.43518)
```

distance gives you the distance to the closest point in a geometry:

```
    In [33]: gf.to_crs(6622).buffer(10).distance(Point(-3597505.980,-2115793.588))
    Out[33]:
    0      0.000000
    1    643.377576
    dtype: float64
```

And you can do a lot more, just look at the documentation
https://geopandas.org/index.html

Also look at shapely's documentation to see how to project a single point https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#shapely.ops.transform

Comment: Please i keep getting this error, even though the first line converts the dataframe to geodataframe:
'Series' object has no attribute 'to_crs'

Comment: here is the code:
`def within(df, lon, lat, rad): 
    geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(df.lon, df.lat)]
    df = df.drop(['lon', 'lat'], axis=1)
    gf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, crs="EPSG:4326", geometry=geometry)
    gf.to_crs(6622).buffer(rad)
    gfd=gf.to_crs(6622).buffer(rad).intersects(Point(lon,lat))
    gfd['dist']=gfd.to_crs(6622).buffer(rad).distance(Point(lon,lat))
    return gfd`

Comment: when you compute the `intersects` part you lose the geodataframe and get a series:

this becomes a pandas series: `gf.to_crs(6622).buffer(10).intersects(Point(-3597505.980,-2115793.588))`